# Prove If ${A \cup B = B'}$, then $B = \emptyset$ and $A=X$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, solution-verification

Assume: if $A\cup B = B'$,  then $B\neq\emptyset$
Let $x \in B$
$→ x ∉ B'$
$→x ∉ A\cup B\quad(∵A\cup B = B')$
$→x ∉ A$  and $x ∉ B$   (De Morgan's law)
$→ x ∉ B$
This is a contadiction!
$∴$  if $A\cup B = B'$,  then  $B=\emptyset$

Let  $x \in A$
$→ x \in A\cup \emptyset$
$→ x \in (A\cup B)\quad(∵ B = \emptyset)$
$→ x \in B'\quad(∵ A\cup B = B' )$
$→ x \in \emptyset'\quad(∵ B = \emptyset)$
$→ x \in X$
$∴ X \subseteq A$
Similarly  $A \subseteq X$
Hence $A = X$
$∴$  if  $A\cup B = B'$,   then $B=\emptyset$, implies  $A=X$
$' ∴$  if  $A\cup B = B'$,   then  $B=0$ and  $A=X'$

Is this correct?. Are there other simple solutions? Can you offer some assistance, please?

Actually, these types of questions are taken lots of time for me. Before solving these questions should I got an idea about the position of sets, consider the situation of the problem.

Comment: Actually it's almost accurate! Just change "assume" for "Proposition" or "something you'll prove" from that, notice that your second part is not necessary, because you already have proved  $B=\emptyset$. Then $A\cup B = A$ and by hypothesis $A\cup B = B'$ so $A= \emptyset ' = X$

Comment: @Valerin Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Proposition**

If $A\cup B = B^{c}$, then $B = \varnothing$ and $A = X$.

**Proof**

Suppose otherwise that $B\neq\varnothing$. Therefore there exists an object $b\in B = (A\cup B)^{c} = A^{c}\cap B^{c}$.

This means that $b\in B\cap B^{c} = \varnothing$, which is an absurd. Therefore $B = \varnothing$.

Consequently, one has that $A = A\cup\varnothing = A\cup B = B^{c} = \varnothing^{c} = X$, and we are done.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome! I am glad to be of help.

Answer (score 1):

$\varnothing=B\cap B'=B\cap(A\cup B)=\overbrace{(A\cap B)}^{\subset\ B}\cup \overbrace{(B\cap B)}^{B}=B$

It implies $A=A\cup\varnothing=A\cup B=B'=X$